# Magento 2 - getDestStreet from RateRequest returns NULL in collectRates

Tags: php, magento, magento2

i made my own module to add a custom shipping method. Everything works fine except getting the destination street and city in the `collectRates` function.

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
```

Comments from the file: 
**/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address/RateRequest.php**

```
* @method \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest setDestCity(string $value)
* @method string getDestCity()
* @method \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest setDestStreet(string $value)
* @method string getDestStreet()
```

Unfortunately both return `NULL`. Also when I try `print_r(json_encode($request->getData()));`
I get `"dest_street":null,"dest_city":null` in my print output.

I need those two informations in order to make my calculations of the price.

Does someone has the same issue?

Comment: Was the shipping address wasn't set in the order/cart?

Comment: As you can see in code I want to have the destination-city and destination-street